# Max zoom scale in iOS 6.0 maps?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, zooming, ios6, ios6-maps

i have been throtting through the iOS 6.0 Map documentation, but I am unable to find any way to define a max zoom on the MKMapView.

Have anyone found a way to do this ? I had a method that worked on the 5.1.1 maps, but it listenes to `zoomScale`, which the modern map doesn't have (making the app crash in the new iOS)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault was found in the map provider side. A limit to the Google maps zoom scale was instated, without much warning from the map service provider themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You set the zoom level by setting the region associated with the map. See MKCoordinateRegion and perhaps MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance. I am finding that the MapKit isn't responding correctly to these calls in Xcode 4.5, though. It seems there is perhaps an undocumented maximum zoom level that precludes me from getting the right zoom using the defined API.